# Intellij warning about a null check after a SoftAssertion

Tags: java, intellij-idea, assertj

I have some tests in which I've created multiple validator functions that run several assertions on each test case. I've set up these validators to have an instance of `SoftAssertions` that is passed to each one, and `assertAll()` is called once all of the validator functions have run. For one of my validators, I have the following assertions:

```
TestArtifact artifactA = testArtifacts.getArtifactA();
softAsserts.assertThat(artifactA)
    .as("TestArtifactA should not be null")
    .isNotNull();

if (artifactA != null) {
    softAsserts.assertThat(artifactA.getTimestamp())
        .isEqualTo(expectedTimestamp);

    // additional assertions omitted
}
```

It's my understanding that, since `SoftAssertions` will only fail a test case when the `assertAll()` function is called, the null check above is necessary, in case the above `SoftAssertion` is false. However, in Intellij, I'm getting a warning message on the if statement, saying:

```
Condition 'artifactA != null' is always 'true'
```

I've confirmed that the warning goes away if the `isNotNull()` soft assert is removed. Is this warning just a false alarm from Intellij? Or am I missing something about `SoftAssertions` that actually makes the null check after the assertion unnecessary?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, the first soft assertion will fail only if `assertAll()` is invoked so the null check is needed. From my point of view, the IntelliJ warning is a bug / false positive. Is there a particular reason why you don't use a normal assertion for the null check?

Comment: Please provide the dependencies versions used in your code sample. Thanks